# Obj-C encoded URL string works in my method but not in IBAction

Tags: objective-c, string, url, encode

My app requires the conversion of a string into a URL, and I want the URL to load when a button is pressed.  The encoded URL loads correctly in my method:

```
 NSString *urlString = [@"http://bit.ly/1m48xKC" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

But when I move the last line into my IBAction as follows:

```
 -(IBAction)textLink {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplicaton]openURL:url];
   }
```

the compiler gives me a warning that the url is an incompatible pointer, the same error that I would have gotten had I not encoded the url in the first place.  All variables are declared in my .h and synthesize in my .m.

Can any of you explain my mistake?

Thank you,

Eli

Comment: Where is `url` defined then?

Comment: `sharedApplicaton` instead of `sharedApplicaton` is a typo error?

Comment: @Larme you missed "i" again. :) `sharedApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

If `url` is a synthesized property then you need:

```
-(IBAction)textLink {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplicaton]openURL:self.url];
}
```

in order to access the property getter method.